# How to get host IP and hostname using Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I am trying to create a task that will get the host target IP address and host-name that are in the inventory then save it to a file in the local directory.

Would love to save the data like this:

```
hostname:ip-address
```

where to start?

Comment: In the documentation for [`inventory_hostname`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) as well as in the [`facts` section](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variables-discovered-from-systems-facts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using"`delegate_to`", I tried that on my computer and it worked properly. I put the first step to delete the file if it exists so it can be executed multiple times. This is a very fast example, I suggest to use variables for the path, etc. But I think you can get the idea

```
---
- hosts: your_inventory

  tasks:
    - name: delete the file if exists
      file:
        path: /home/yourpath/host_ip.txt
          state: absent
      delegate_to: localhost
    - name: get data to a file
      lineinfile:
        dest: /home/yourpath/host_ip.txt
        create: yes
        line: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_hostname}}:{{hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_default_ipv4.address}}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: If i understood properly my answer fits his question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803839/how-to-get-host-ip-and-hostname-using-ansible

Comment: Hey let me give it a try then tell you.

Comment: I just noticed that i deleted the inventory (- hosts)  from the code let me add it.

Comment: Thanks alot it worked, but can someone refrain from also adding the localhost group?? Like in the inventory I have two groups, local which is the localhost and Servers which are multiple ip address of servers. So I would love to specify to only pick the hostname and ip of hosts that are in the Servers groups.